ActiveMQ Artemis shared storage doesnt work as expected
I am actually trying to add a disk to VMs as shared stored for ActiveMQ Artemis 2.6 with a filesystem attached running on shared disk attached to both master and slave. Both the instances have the shared disk mounted formatted with ext4 with the data folder shared and added as volume at /data-volume/artemis/data. The broker and artemis.profile config settings point to this shared directory for journal, paging, bindings and large-messages. I am not seeing the slave getting active when master is shutdown. Can someone share some insight?
mq-master:/var/lib/artemis-master# df -h
Filesystem       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs            1.6G  512K  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1    99G   16G   79G  17% /
tmpfs            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p15  124M   12M  113M  10% /boot/efi
tmpfs            1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1012
/dev/nvme0n2      98G  103M   98G   1% /data-volume/artemis/data

mq-slave:/var/lib/artemis-slave# df -h
Filesystem       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs            1.6G  512K  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1    99G  4.5G   90G   5% /
tmpfs            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p15  124M   12M  113M  10% /boot/efi
tmpfs            1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1013
/dev/nvme0n2      98G   44K   98G   1% /data-volume/artemis/data

Log:
2024-12-10 20:11:38,788 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap] AMQ101000: Starting ActiveMQ Artemis Server
2024-12-10 20:11:38,803 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221000: backup Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=true,journalDirectory=/data-volume/artemis/data/journal,bindingsDirectory=/data-volume/artemis/data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=/data-volume/artemis/data/large-messages,pagingDirectory=/data-volume/artemis/data/paging)
2024-12-10 20:11:38,808 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221032: Waiting to become backup node
2024-12-10 20:11:38,809 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221033: ** got backup lock
2024-12-10 20:11:38,866 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221012: Using AIO Journal
2024-12-10 20:11:38,906 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 2,684,354,560
2024-12-10 20:11:38,963 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
2024-12-10 20:11:38,964 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
2024-12-10 20:11:38,964 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
2024-12-10 20:11:38,965 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-mqtt-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: MQTT
2024-12-10 20:11:38,966 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-openwire-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: OPENWIRE
2024-12-10 20:11:38,966 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
2024-12-10 20:11:39,016 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221109: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Backup Server version 2.6.0 [fd9905f1-b72d-11ef-a36e-42010acc03c8] started, waiting live to fail before it gets active
2024-12-10 20:11:39,080 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Initialized activemq-branding plugin
2024-12-10 20:11:39,139 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Initialized artemis-plugin plugin
2024-12-10 20:11:39,200 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221031: backup announced
2024-12-10 20:11:39,452 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Initialising hawtio services
2024-12-10 20:11:39,463 INFO  [io.hawt.system.ConfigManager] Configuration will be discovered via system properties
2024-12-10 20:11:39,465 INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.JmxTreeWatcher] Welcome to hawtio 1.5.5 : http://hawt.io/ : Don't cha wish your console was hawt like me? ;-)
2024-12-10 20:11:39,466 INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.UploadManager] Using file upload directory: /var/lib/artemis-slave/tmp/uploads
2024-12-10 20:11:39,477 INFO  [io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter] Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "activemq" authorized role(s): "amq" role principal classes: "org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal"
2024-12-10 20:11:39,497 INFO  [io.hawt.web.JolokiaConfiguredAgentServlet] Jolokia overridden property: [key=policyLocation, value=file:/var/lib/artemis-slave/etc/jolokia-access.xml]
2024-12-10 20:11:39,513 INFO  [io.hawt.web.RBACMBeanInvoker] Using MBean [hawtio:type=security,area=jmx,rank=0,name=HawtioDummyJMXSecurity] for role based access control
2024-12-10 20:11:39,589 INFO  [io.hawt.system.ProxyWhitelist] Initial proxy whitelist: [localhost, 127.0.0.1, 10.204.3.200, mq-slave]
2024-12-10 20:11:39,757 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241001: HTTP Server started at http://0.0.0.0:8161
2024-12-10 20:11:39,758 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241002: Artemis Jolokia REST API available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/console/jolokia
2024-12-10 20:11:39,758 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241004: Artemis Console available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/console
2024-12-10 20:11:45,715 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]
2024-12-10 20:11:45,715 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]


How come you're using such an old version of ActiveMQ Artemis? Version 2.6.0 was released in 2018 (over 6 years ago now). The latest version is 2.38.0 which contains hundreds of bug fixes plus lots of new features as compared to 2.6.0.

How are you shutting down the primary broker? If you're shutting it down gracefully (e.g. using ctrl+c vs. kill -9 <pid>) then that actually won't trigger failover by default due to the value of failover-on-shutdown.

Any feedback here?

Thanks for your response, sorry for the delay. Unfortunately the client application supports only this version of active mq artemis so we had to go with it as necessary for the application side support. To your second point, the value of the setting in HA policy is set to true for failure on shutdown as per the documentation the backup/slave instance should be active(failover). Please let me know if you have any further questions or if was able to answer your questions correctly.

All versions of ActiveMQ Artemis released after 2.6.0 should be backwards compatible with clients using 2.6.0. Can you verify your configuration works by running both brokers on the same machine (e.g. listening different ports) using a shared, local directory and performing the same steps? If so, that means something is likely wrong with the configuration or ability of your shared storage device (i.e. it's maintaining a lock when it shouldn't). If not, that means something is wrong with  your broker configuration and you'll need to provide details from broker.xml for further investigation.
